# Change my Asus fn+F4 key

Tags: windows, windows-vista, function-keys

My fn+F4 key is the internet browser, and it is set to be internet explore. I want to make it to be chrome, is that possible to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if there's a laptop specific solution, but check out [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), a great software to make any key do whatever you want.

Also, make sure Chrome is your default browser, in case the key launches your default browser, not specifically IE.

Comment: AutoHotKey will probably not work. Google for [“autohotkey fn”](http://www.google.com/search?q=autohotkey+fn+key) and you will find plenty of [information](http://www.autohotkey.net/~daonlyfreez/tutorials/3p/Veil/fnkey.htm) about how the `Fn` key is different from other keys (similar to the `F-Lock` key on Logitech keyboards). It does not signal a key the way that other modifiers like `Ctrl`, `Alt`, `Shift`, etc. do, but rather, it modifies the other key’s scancode at the hardware level (ie, the keyboard controller). In this case, the `Fn+F4` combo sends the scancode of the `Web Browser` key.

Comment: @Synetech The `Fn` key [can be remapped](http://www.autohotkey.net/~daonlyfreez/tutorials/3p/Veil/fnkey.htm) on some keyboards.

Comment: @iglvzx, yes, *some*. That’s why I said it would *probably* not work. Even with those that *can* be, usually default to a low-level mod.

Answer (score 1):

Just set Chrome as your default browser. Go to `Wrench menu->Options->Basics tab->Default browser: Make Chrome my default browser`. Now whenever a web browser needs to be opened (including via the <kbd>Fn+F4</kbd> hotkey), Chrome will automatically be run instead of IE.